# Android Studio - Re enable popup marked as Don't show again

Tags: android, android-studio, ide

I'm user of Android Studio v1.0.2 and its SVN features.

When working with a SVN project and adding new files, Android Studio used to show a popup asking if I'd like to Schedule the file for addition. I ever hit NO, until one day I put "Don't show again".

Now I need that feature because I don't like to manually put ADD to every new file on a project.

Is there a fix without deleting all config?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to **Settings** -> **Version Control** -> **Confirmation** -> **When files are created**
Choose **Show options before adding to version control**

Comment: this is what I am exactly looking for. Because once if you gave "NO and checked the Don't ask me again" in "Schedule for Addition" popup, it's difficult to change the settings back. Thanks @y.feizi

Answer (score 0):

> In android studio go to **file** -> **settings** -> **version control** -> then
>   choose ur **version control type** -> and there should be **reset link** on top
>   right corner